# NSTableView. How to override autoscroll behavior?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I've got an NSTableView that displays (via bindings) data from an NSTreeController. The application frequently appends/changes data to/in the bound array.

The problem is that if the user has selected a row in the table, but has scrolled so that the selected data is no longer visible, when the application updates the array it causes the display to auto-scroll so that the selected line is once again on screen. This is pretty 
frustrating to users, especially since new data can arrive at any time.

Is there any way of disabling this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to subclass `NSTableView` and override `-scrollRowToVisible:`, temporarily bracketing the call to `super`. This may also require a custom BOOL ivar in your subclass to keep track of whether you want to scroll.

I would start by setting a breakpoint there to see when exactly the autoscroll is triggered. This should help to find the proper moments to toggle the ivar.

Comment: As far as I know, Costique's solution is currently the only way to deal with this issue. It is unfortunate, because other things will break if you simply override `-scrollRowToVisible:` and don't invoke super's implementation. In my case I had to modify my network code to add a class method `+isInsertingNewDataFromRemote`, and then have my custom table view check that flag from within `-scrollRowToVisible:`, and only invoke super's implementation if that flag is `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an `NSTreeController` with an `NSOutlineView` or an `NSArrayController` with an `NSTableView`? Using an `NSTreeController` with an `NSTableView` doesn't make a lot of sense to me?

If you're using an `NSTableView` you should probably be using an `NSArrayController` to manage its data and this rearranging of the rows is a feature of the `NSArrayController`. Try turning off the *Auto Rearrange Content* option on your controller within IB.

When it's on, the array controller will rearrange its objects on addition, removal and changes to objects that would affect the sort ordering (if any) and cause any table views or outline views to reload their data.

I don't know of a similar feature for `NSTreeController` mainly because I don't use it since it's never worked well for me. I, sadly, recommend to just use the datasource methods for the `NSOutlineView` and supply your data the old-fashioned way. In my experience, `NSTreeController` is only well suited for the most trivial tasks.

Comment: NSTreeController has improved a lot in 10.7; it's now a lot more useful than in previous releases.